# Open UDP socket between source and destination, modify it and forward it to the original destination

Tags: c, linux, sockets, routes, ipv6

I am running a simple network that contains 2 nodes and a gateway. My scenario is as follows: Node1 wants to send a UDP IPv6 socket to Node2 via the Gateway which has to open the sockets, verifies data and then forwarding it.

I configured an internal network between Node1 and Gateway having an address of **aaaa::/20**, and an other network between Gateway and Node2 having an address of **aaab::/20**. I modified Node1 routing table to send packets destined to **aaab::/20** network via its **aaaa::/20** interface connected to the Gateway, and configured the former to forward packets.

My problem is by doing so, the Gateway became completely transparent. I want my gateway to be able to catch sockets even if they are not destined to it, opening them, modifying them and forwarding them to their original destination. Googled this and I found suggestions to use iptables, but i'm not expert with them.

I'm using 3 virtual machines under linux and programming with c. Any help please?!!

Comment: Not sure if this'd get more attention at [serverfault](http://serverfault.com/). It'd also be helpful if you tried to format your question.  Its *really* hard to read in its current form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iptables is not something to be afraid of ;) it has its own defined C functions. Go through the interface library and apply it to your own case. That is to run a program in the gateway, to capture all packets passing through it. There is [documentation](http://www.bani.com.br/lang/en/2012/05/programmatically-managing-iptables-rules-in-c-iptc/).

Comment: if you need a solid code with what you intend to do, you may also have a look at nProbe source code.